# How can I create a list of panels that contains fields connect by LiveBinding to a Dataset in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, livebindings

Delphi XE5 update 2

I am looking for a list of "panels" that will have the same layout (same controls) and each panel is created for each record of the DataSet existent.

I need to use LiveBindings preferably. But if that is not possible I would like to know how to do the list of panels thing.

You can see on this image below an example in a list of contacts (marked in red)

[image]

I remember that in Delphi 6 VCL we had a component that were capable of such thing, we only needed to add the required DBEdit's and other DB Control on the first panel and it created a panel for each record of the table accordingly.

Comment: @KenWhite That is the answer I was looking for, could you please add it as the answer so I can give you the credit that you desire. Thank you!

Comment: I've done so, including info on the location for those using XE6 and a link to the latest version on SourceForge. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a sample of doing something very similar to this in the ListView example in the \Samples\FireMonkey Mobile folder. Despite it's location, it's designed for Win32, iOS, and Android targets, so it's actually relevant here. (In XE6, it's in a slightly different location, in the Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Samples\User Interface\ListView folder. The latest version of the sample is also available at SourceForge in the [RAD Studio Demo repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Samples/User%20Interface/ListView/).)

There are samples of creating various types of custom ListItems in the demos in that folder, including some using Live Binding.

Make sure to see the Readme.txt in that folder before opening any of the projects; it implements some design-time packages that allow you to configure the items in the IDE that require installation before the projects will load/compile. –